# How does this reinterpret_cast work? (Porting C++ to Java)

Tags: java, c++, porting, reinterpret-cast

I have some C++ code I'm trying to port to Java, that looks like this:

```
struct foostruct {
    unsigned char aa : 3;
    bool ab : 1;
    unsigned char ba : 3;
    bool bb : 1;
};

static void foo(const unsigned char* buffer, int length)
{

    const unsigned char *end = buffer + length;

    while (buffer < end)
    {
        const foostruct bar = *(reinterpret_cast<const foostruct*>(buffer++));
        //read some values from struct and act accordingly
    }

}
```

What is the `reinterpret_cast` doing?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805058/is-there-cast-in-java-similar-to-reinterpret-cast-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its basically saying the 8 bits represented at the current pointer should be interpreted as a "foostruct".

In my opinion it would be better written as follows:

```
const unsigned char aa = *buffer & 0x07;
const bool ab          = (*buffer & 0x08) != 0;
const unsigned char ba = (*buffer & 0x70) >> 4;
const bool bb          = (*buffer & 0x80) != 0;
```

I think it is far more obvious what is being done then.  I think you may well find it easier to port to Java this way too ...

Comment: Beware: the right-shifts are wrong (right shift by 3, 4 and 7, respectively) 'Better' is debatable...

Comment: @Pontus: You are quite right I forgot to right shift ba.  The 2 bools are NOT right shifted .. they are greater thans (as greater than returns a bool).

Comment: Ah. Correcting the correction: that's collaborative... I read what I expected to see, as usual!

Comment: It is better to always use `!= 0` to convert to boolean. With `>` it is rather confusing.

Comment: @starblue:  Just for you I changed it to != but, personally, I find it no more difficult to read, however thats me, as others obviously are your point is taken.

Comment: @Goz: It's not only for starblue. When checking whether a value is not equal `0`, it's better to test `!= 0`.

Answer (score 4):

It does what a classic C-style `(const foostruct *)buffer` would do at worst: tells C++ to ignore all safety and that you really know what you are doing. In this case, that the `buffer` actually consists of `foostruct`s, which in turn are bit fields overlain on single 8 bit characters. Essentially, you can do the same in Java by just getting the bytes and doing the shift and mask operations yourself.

Answer (score 2):

you have a pointer to unsigned char right? Now imagine that the bits pointed to by the pointer are treated as though it were an object of type foostruct. That's what reinterpret_cast does - it reinterprets the bit pattern to be a memory representation of another type...